# How can I access a hard drive from another computer over a network?

Tags: linux, networking, hard-drive

I have two linux boxes, both Debian 10, both connected to a network via WiFi. I'll call them "computer A" and "computer B". I want to access computer A's hard drive from computer B. Please note that I don't want to mount the disk, just get a device file corrasponding to it. This means that using FTP to share the files is not an option. (as far as I know). Is there a network protocol or other method the allows me to read and write from and to a device file on computer A, which then reads and writes from and to the disk on computer B?

Sorry if this question is a bit wordy. Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68932/how-can-i-share-files-between-two-linux-machines-over-lan

Comment: https://www.pks.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.2/html/opensuse-manual_en/manual/sec.filetrans.share.html

Comment: thanks @spikey_richie it works great. could you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @user1686 has done the honors.